# PHP app displays error about vendor libraries

Tags: php, composer-php, vendor

I'm trying to install an app called **CollectiveAccess** on a subdomain, and when I enter the website it pops an error.

> Your installation is missing required vendor libraries

It has an option to auto install them or change them, but when I click to change them, it pops another error:

> Automatic installation of the required vendor libraries failed: Composer installation failed: Error in argument 1, char 2: option not found r; Usage: php-cgi [-q] [-h] [-s] [-v] [-i] [-f ]; php-cgi [args...]; -a Run interactively; -b | Bind Path for external FASTCGI Server mode; -C Do not chdir to the script's directory; -c | Look for php.ini file in this directory; -n No php.ini file will be used; -d foo[=bar] Define INI entry foo with value 'bar'; -e Generate extended information for debugger/profiler; -f Parse . Implies `-q'; -h This help; -i PHP information; -l Syntax check only (lint); -m Show compiled in modules; -q Quiet-mode. Suppress HTTP Header output.; -s Display colour syntax highlighted source.; -v Version number; -w Display source with stripped comments and whitespace.; -z Load Zend extension .; -T Measure execution time of script repeated times.; Error in argument 1, char 2: option not found r; ERROR: Invalid installer signature

Help!! There's no info anywhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Composer’s hash changes periodically. You likely have a hard coded hash the installer script is checking against, which does not match the one given. Try reading the docs on how to install programmatically here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-to-install-composer-programmatically.md